# Restricting AdSense ads' language

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, language

My users are seeing (spammy) English ads on my website that's geared purely towards native speakers of another language many of whom know no English. I would like to restrict the language of AdSense ads to that language. Is it possible, and how?

Comment: Keep in mind that AdSense ads are targeted to individuals.   The ads that you see on your own website are the ones that are chosen *for you*.  The ads that your visitors see are not likely to be the same ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google itself

> **Language targeting**: Our technology can also determine the primary language of a page. If your content is in a language supported by our program, AdSense will target ads in the appropriate language to your content. We may look at the language of the pages a user is currently viewing, or has recently viewed, to determine which ads to show. In this case, AdSense may target ads in the user's detected language rather than in the language of your content. Learn more about ad targeting by language.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9713?hl=en

> In addition, we may look at the language of the pages a user is viewing or has recently viewed to determine which ads to show. This means that we may detect the language from either pages that the person had viewed in the past, or the page that they are currently viewing. In this case, AdSense may target ads in the user's detected language rather than in the language of your content.

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2753586?hl=en

I would look also at your page language declaration in the `<head>`. Is it set correcty as the language of the document content?

Anyway, you should report a violation if you see spammy ads as Google suggest here https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2631197?hl=en

Comment: So basically, the answer is that you can hint, but not restrict?

Comment: Also, the language is set in `<html lang='CC'>`, is that what you mean or should it be declared elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. About the language: yes, you should declare it inside the html tag. What's the language of your document? Anyway: I think it's just a tiny hint (the content itself speaks) for helping crawlers to understand. As you saw, the decision depends on the AdSense system.